# Get Twitter Access Token using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth

Is there any way that we can get Twitter access token through JavaScript? It is for a MVC project.

Here is what I got. It would be great if someone help me as most of the developer documents are really confusing.

I have included the include the `widgets.js` script.

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have downloaded Hello.js 
#include this in the head
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/hello.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://adodson.com/hello.js/src/modules/twitter.js"></script>
</head>

#Include this in Script (Javascript)

<script type ="text/javascript>
hello('twitter').login(function () {
                    var Twitter = hello('twitter').getAuthResponse();
                    if (Twitter.access_token != null) {
                        alert(Twitter.access_token);

                    }

                    else { }
                });
</script>
```